# How to search for a string pattern and print the total values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Market  Region  No_of_Orders    Profit  Sales
Africa  Western Africa  251 -12,901.51  78,476.06
Afr3ica Southern Africa 85  11,768.58   51,319.50
Africa  North Africa    182 21,643.08   86,698.89
Afr2ica Eastern Africa  110 8,013.04    44,182.60
Africa  Central Africa  103 15,606.30   61,689.99
Eur1ope Western Europe  964 82,091.27   656,637.14
EurYope Southern Europe 338 18,911.49   215,703.93
```

How to filter and print the total market values which have typos !! I tried like this

```
-->result['Market'].str.contains(u'\|123\|').count()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Kishan. Please add to your question what you have already tried. Then we can help you from there.

Comment: IIUC, it should be `...str.contains('1|2|3')`

Comment: I wanted the count of the total length of the values which has 7 characters on the column

Comment: update question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
masked = df['Market'].str.contains("1|2|3")
```

**to filter:**

```
print(df[masked])
```

**to count:**

```
print(masked.sum())
```

Comment: I wanted the count of the length of the strings which has 7 characters on the column

Comment: do you want to count the rows which have 7 characters in a row of the column?

Comment: try `df[df['Market'].str.len() == 7]`

Comment: I want to do the both in one line like search the string which has length of 7  and the total count of it